# Fail to make wss websocket connection in Chrome, with multi domain SSL SAN certificate

Tags: ssl, websocket, certificate

Can someone kindly help me understand the following and suggest a possible fix?

**Problem**: Secure websocket (wss) connection fails in Chrome browser, when using a multi domain (SAN) SSL certificate

**Details**: We have a multi domain SSL SAN certificate that covers, say, webapp.example.com and websocket.example.com. The page https://webapp.example.com/ loads correctly (the domain is verified correctly against the SAN certificate by the browser, and a 'lock' icon is shown to indicate that the connection is secure). However, the said web application on that page also attempts to makes a connection to wss://websocket.example.com/. This connection is failing with ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

**A weak hypothesis for the failure**: This error is possibly because

1. The browser first opens an SSL connection to https://webapp.example.com after verifying webapp.example.com as a valid domain in the SAN certificate
2. When a connection is made to wss://websocket.example.com, the name 'websocket.example.com' does not match with the domain that has been previously verified (webapp.example.com).

**Question**: Is it possible to make this work? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis is wrong. The certificate validation is always done against the domain in the currently accessed URL. It is not done based on some URL previously accessed, even if the provided certificate was the same.

It is more likely that the domain you access is actually not contained in the multi-domain certificate. Note that an entry of `webapp.example.com` or `example.com` in the certificate does not cover `websocket.example.com` or similar in the URL.

Comment: Hello Steffen, Thanks for answering. I wasn't very confident of my weak hypothesis either :) But the SAN certificate does include both the domains. So, I am guessing  Chrome in specific or browsers in general cannot handle this sort of mixed usage in the web page. I tried to look at Chromium implementation but it wasn't easy to locate this code. Any ideas on how to proceed further?

Comment: @vsv: I'm pretty sure that this is not a bug in Chrome since what you describe is not an unusual setup. If you would provide a setup to reproduce the problem I could have a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. This is happening on a customer's setup with restricted access. I will ping back if we're able to replicate it elsewhere.